# What permissions are required to create a new work item type in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am new to creating work item types in TFS and want to create a new Work Item type.

I looked at work item template option, but that is not sufficient for me.
I need to add few new fields and have a customized form.

From search I got information about Work Item Type definition but I am looking for some detailed example.

Also I would like to know the permissions needed to add a new work item type.

I got administrator privileges for my project, but not on TFS as a whole.

With that can I add a new template for my project.

Please provide me direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to create a new work item type you have to change the process template that the project is using. This is not easy and there are basically two options as outlined in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194914%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Quoting from that article:

> account must be a member of the **Team
>   Foundation Administrators** group or
>   have the **Create new projects**
>   permission set to *Allow.*
>   Additionally, your user account must
>   be a member of the **Windows
>   SharePoint Services Administrator**
>   role and a member of the **SQL Server
>   Reporting Services Content Manager**
>   role. So quite a few permissions are
>   required.